# How to correctly use os.Args in golang?

Tags: command-line, go

I need to use config in my go code and I want to load config path from command-line. 
I try:

```
if len(os.Args) > 1 { 
        configpath := os.Args[1]
        fmt.Println("1") // For debug
    } else {
        configpath := "/etc/buildozer/config"
        fmt.Println("2")
    }
```

Then I use config:

```
configuration := config.ConfigParser(configpath)
```

When I launch my go file with parameter (or without) I receive similar error

```
# command-line-arguments
src/2rl/buildozer/buildozer.go:21: undefined: configpath
```

How should I correctly use os.Args?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Define `configPath` outside the scope of your `if`.

```
configPath := ""

if len(os.Args) > 1 { 
  configPath = os.Args[1] 
  fmt.Println("1") // For debugging purposes 
} else { 
  configPath = "/etc/buildozer/config"
  fmt.Println("2") 
}
```

Note the '`configPath =`' (instead of `:=`) inside the `if`.

That way `configPath` is defined before and is still visible after the `if`.

See more at "[Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)" / "[Variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)".

Answer (score 2):

For another approach, you can wrap the logic in a function:

```
package main
import "os"

func configPath(a []string) string {
   switch len(a) {
      case 1: return "/etc/buildozer/config"
      default: return os.Args[1]
   }
}

func main() {
   config := configPath(os.Args)
   println(config)
}
```

this avoids the scoping issue.